# UIScrollView content size fixed to 600x600(Main.storyboard size)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, autolayout

I've been facing this issue from past 2 weeks and not yet got a solution.

I'm using UIScrollview in my application where the problem exists.
Generally in my app, there is dynamic text and images with different sizes will come from webservices. For example, imagine the Facebook Newsfeed. My application is similar to the Facebook newsfeed. Sometimes, there will be only text, sometimes there will be text and images. And comments for that post.

As i've seen in many links, the heirrarchy i'm following is **SuperView-->UIScrollView-->Content View** and the elements are placed in that content view. I'm assigning the constraints from the elements in the contentview to the Superview (**ContentView --- constraints -- SuperView**). When the content in the view exceeds the size of the superview, it has to scroll. But the scrollview content size is limited to the size of 600x600 i.e., in main.storyboard, when we design for **W any x H any** size. I've seen many tutorials and searched many sites. But following them gives me no luck.

Any help is appreciable.

Comment: I think autolayout has nothing to do with the content size of the scrollview. Instead it only handles the frame of the scrollview wrt the given UI element. For content size it can be changed at runtime wrt the content to be shown.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is how to set up a scrollView in *Interface Builder* from scratch that works with *Auto Layout*.

1. Start with a new ViewController.  Drag out a scrollView such that it fills the view.  Untick *Constrain to margins* and constrain the left, top, right, and bottom edges of this scrollView to the left, top, right, and bottom of its superview with offsets of 0.  This allows the scollView to fill the screen on any device in any orientation.  You can make your scrollView take up less of the screen if you like, just make sure it is fully contrained.
2. Add a view to your scrollView. This should be the only top level view on your scrollView and it will serve as your contentView.
3. Constrain the left, top, right, and bottom edges of this contentView to the left, top, right, and bottom of the scrollView with offsets of 0.  At this point, you will see warnings about ambiguous content size.  That is because you haven't told it yet how big your content view will be.
4. To size the contentView, add width and height constraints to the contentView. If you want it to scroll, the width and height must be larger than the width and height of the scrollView itself. If you only want to scroll vertically, set the width of the contentView to be equal to the width of the scrollView.  To do this, in the *Document Outline* view, <kbd>control</kbd>-drag from the contentView to the scrollView and select *Equal Widths* from the pop up.
5. If you want to be able to change the height of your contentView from code (to account for dynamic content), first create a height constraint for your contentView by <kbd>control</kbd>-dragging within the contentView and selecting *Height* from the pop up.  Create an `IBOutlet` to the height constraint by <kbd>control</kbd>-dragging from the height constraint (found in the *Document Outline* view) to your ViewController's code.  Give the outlet a name like `scrollViewHeight` then set the height with a value like `scrollViewHeight.constant = 2000` when you need to change the scrollView's height.

Comment: can u pls explain it more briefly the 5th point? May be its the answer i was looking for @vacawama

Answer (score 3):

Simply add your UIScrollView to your UIViewController's view in the storyboard and add the appropriate constraints in the interface builder.

Then, build your content view in the code and give it any frame you want, now start adding your controls to this content view and calculate the size of each one (especially the height), and at the end you have the total height of your controls.

Now set the frame of the content view to match that height and add it as a sub view to your scroll view, then set the content size in the code like this:

```
_scrollView.contentSize = contentView.frame.size;
```

Another note, do this changes to the sizes in the viewDidLayoutSubviews to avoid any problems with different screen sizes but be careful, this event is called many times so have a BOOL or something to ensure that the code that creates the view and add it to the scroll view is executed once, e.g. like this

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
     [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
     if (! built) {
         // Do everything I explained above here

        built = YES;
        [self.view layoutSubviews];
     }
}
```

Comment: i'm using autolayout and in my screen there may be only text or text and image or text and question with 2 - 5 options which are dynamic. And there is a tableview.

Comment: It doesn't matter what you are adding to the content view, as long as you are keeping the total height of these controls, what I told you shall work